# How to merge "develop" branch from different people in git flow branching model?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-branch, git-flow

Is "develop" branch in git flow branching model shared by different people? So we have to manually push "develop" and pull it to merge?

Or each person have his "develop" branch and people need to get "feature" branch by "git flow feature publish" and "git flow feature pull"?

Which way is correct in using git flow branching model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Git Flow, the `develop` branch is one of the long-running branches that "everyone should share."  This implies two things:

1. Work should not be done on `develop`, but in feature branches branching off of `develop`.
2. Changes to `develop`, such as merged feature branches, should generally be made public quickly.

If everyone were to have their own `develop` branch, this would be very disorganized, especially in the merge-commit history!

Answer (score 3):

To extend a little more what thirtythreeforty said:

Develop contains unstable code.
When you want to create a new feature you create a separate FROM develop

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature/123-name-of-feature
```

After you have finished your work and you have already **added and committed your work** (i.e. git add && git commit), now it's time to merge your branch to develop, the best practices suggest to use no fast forward btw.

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff feature/123-name-of-feature
git push origin develop
```

Now everyone can pull develop and repeat this cycle. Of course, I am skipping the process of merging to qa, stage and master because I don't know your git workflow.

As a suggestion, [I will give you a document](http://www.cakedc.com/git-workflow) explaining the git Workflow that we use in my job

Comment: Thanks, so when everyone push their local develop branch, with different feature branch on it, will conflict and need to merge sometimes? Then the develop branch won't be a simple straight line, right?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The possibility of conflicts will always be there no matter what, however with this approach if everyone is working on a separate feature branch it will be not that common that conflicts occur.

Comment: I got it. I had this question because there's no "git flow develop publish [foo]" command. But it means we still have to combine some native git commands like "git push origin develop" or "git pull origin develop". Appreciate your answer and response.